# Reporting opportunities for users without roles

Tags: reporting, user-management, role-hierarchy

As part of our organisation procedures, when a user leaves they are removed from their role. This is to avoid them still appearing in queues etc. which are assigned based on roles.

We leave closed Opportunities owned by the user. This is useful because you can see who actually closed a deal historically.

However, we have a problem with reporting. As the documentation says "Opportunities owned by users who do not have a role in your organization's hierarchy are omitted from opportunity, forecast, and sales reports." (https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_oppforesales.htm)
So what this means is that our report of sales this year is not complete as it omits sales closed by inactive users.

We don't really want to change the ownership of these opportunities to an active user as this distorts the view of who really did the work. I did think about created a "dismissed" role and adding it somewhere in the hierarchy.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found an elegant solution?

Comment: Another option would be to attack the problem of having to remove the role from the user when you inactivate them: is it possible to filter the inactive users from the queues etc where they are being picked up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have recommended creating a  role as you already thought about it. Put it directly under the CEO, as a sibling to all other trees for active users.

You could then create a sharing rule dependent on that role, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the way I will go. I'll just leave this question open a bit longer in case anyone has any other suggestion.